# android activity can not be closed

Tags: android, android-activity

I made a function in my app which will return user to the home activity in the case of error. but the main problem is that when I finish the activity it do not close and keep working unitl it face problem and my app crashes.
I read some related topics in Stackover flow to know how to solve this problem but none of them worked for me. this is my code.

```
private void backhome(String error) {
    // TODO In a case of error this function return us to home page;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    intent.putExtra("error", error);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    finishActivity(0);
    this.finish();
    return;
}
```

[the error image](http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/UylhiH4Db4/2015-11-09_133420.png)

Comment: why are you calling finish 3 times?

Comment: when this function called ?

Comment: I check whether is a sepecific String is empty or not. if it's empty I call this function to move me to previous activity . but It countiues working to face error and make app to crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void backhome(String error) {
// TODO In a case of error this function return us to home page;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
intent.putExtra("error", error);
startActivity(intent);
youractivity.this.finish();
startActivity(intent);
   }
```

but using Bundle args is better.

Comment: I add image to my quesion

Comment: This above code works fine.But the reason why you are getting index outofbounds exception is still i don't understand.so can you temme your plan.?

Comment: can you goto line 255 and paste that code here or put a screenshot here?

Comment: float xnum = (float) (subdelay1 / 1000.0);

Comment: if you are using arraylist anywhere above or below the above code,check that arraylist.the list doesnot have any size.

Comment: Are you sure. Becuse I used arraylists several time in my app and I I used the size() function to get its size. and I didn't face any problem in other pages of my application

Comment: yes,ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception will be caused if your array is empty and you are using that empty list somewhere.